# Save Selected Option in Meta Box

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes

i am going to build my own theme
I try to add select to post_type meta box, but every update post my select not on selected option but show the first option (blank value)

here is my code

```
function mhs_data() {
        global $post;
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="eventmeta_noncename" id="eventmeta_noncename" value="' .
        wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';

        $nisn = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_nisn', true);
        $rel = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_rel', true);
    }

            echo '<p>NISN</p>';
            echo '<input type="text" name="_nisn" value="' . $nisn  . '" class="widefat" />';
            echo '<p>Relationship</p>'; ?>

            <select name="_rel" id="_rel">
                <option value="">Relationship</option>
                <option value="Single" <?php selected( $rel, 'Single' ); ?>>Single</option>
                <option value="Marry" <?php selected( $rel, 'Marry' ); ?>>Marry</option>
            </select>

            <?php 
    }

    function mhs_data_meta($post_id, $post) {
        if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['eventmeta_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) {
        return $post->ID;
        }
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID ))
            return $post->ID;

        $events_meta['_nisn'] = $_POST['_nisn'];
        $events_meta['_rel'] = $_POST['_rel'];

        foreach ($events_meta as $key => $value) { 
            if( $post->post_type == 'revision' ) return; 
            $value = implode(',', (array)$value); 
            if(get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, FALSE)) { 
                update_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
            } else {
                add_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
            }
            if(!$value) delete_post_meta($post->ID, $key);
        }
    }

    add_action('save_post', 'mhs_data_meta', 1, 2);
```

Please help me to correct my code

Comment: I recommend you to use http://codestarframework.com/ is very easy and powerfull framework to save time in this kind of things

Comment: i have to learn code and how it to work, thank for your answer but i think  you like spam comment (comment contain link) and not give me right solution to learn code

Answer (score 0):

Using [Codestar Framework](http://codestarframework.com/) its very simple tu add metaboxes to your custom post, create configuration page, plugins, taxonomies and use the customizer if you prefer use it instead of a configuration page. see the documentation [here](http://codestarframework.com/documentation/) for more information.

in your example, to add a select metabox shuld use a code similar to:

load the framework on your **functions.php**

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/'.$FRAMEWORK_PATH.'/cs-framework/cs-framework.php';
```

edit the **cs-framekork.php** configuration file to active only the features you need:

```
defined('CS_ACTIVE_FRAMEWORK') or define('CS_ACTIVE_FRAMEWORK', false); // if you need it for plugin or configuration page
defined('CS_ACTIVE_METABOX') or define('CS_ACTIVE_METABOX', true);      // if you only need it for metabox
defined('CS_ACTIVE_TAXONOMY') or define('CS_ACTIVE_TAXONOMY', false);
defined('CS_ACTIVE_SHORTCODE') or define('CS_ACTIVE_SHORTCODE', false);
defined('CS_ACTIVE_CUSTOMIZE') or define('CS_ACTIVE_CUSTOMIZE', false);
```

and then in your **function.php** or as I prefer on another file included in your **function.php** register your metabox

```
function register_this_metabox($options)
{

    $options = array(); // this will clean the default cs-framework configuration

    $options[] = array(
        'id' => 'the_metabox',
        'title' => 'Meta Box title',
        'post_type' => 'post', // the post type where the metabox appears
        'context' => 'side',   // metabox position
        'priority' => 'high',
        'sections' => array(   // metabox fields, see the documentation
            array(
                'name' => 'the_metabox_fields',
                'fields' => array(
                    array(
                        'id' => 'the_metabox_select_field',
                        'type'           => 'select',
                        'title'          => 'Select Field',
                        'options'        => array(
                             'opt1'   => 'Option 1',
                             'opt2'   => 'Option 2',
                             'opt3'   => 'Option 3',
                         ),
                        'default_option' => 'Select a option',
                     ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
    return $options;
}

add_filter('cs_metabox_options', 'register_this_metabox');
```

And now you only have to get the values in your theme:

```
$post_metabox = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'the_metabox', true);
$selected_option = $post_metabox['the_metabox_select_field']
```